# I am checking for a file in directory if is not found am throwing an error or else am printing match found

Tags: c

I am using strcmp for comapring the file with same name in the directory.

```
while((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
if(strcmp(dirp->dname,filename) == 0)
{
 print("match found");

}

else
{
printf("match not found");
}
}
```

considering that i have some 500 files in the directory it is checking for all those files and sending error many time till the match is found. i Want to optimize this . please help

Comment: Did you measure the performance? Is *this* really your bottleneck?

Comment: @EOF:  yes it has a performance constraint

Comment: What would be the expected result: To find a file or to not find a file? Which of those two cases would your specific use case (which we do not know) consider a "positive" result?

Comment: @alk.. I am checking if file is found we are going to create another file. if it is not found I am sending the error message using our user defined function

Comment: Ok, then I'd go for *venki*'s proposal (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32246975/694576), removing the message that a file was found.

Comment: thanks @alk for your valuable time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After specific file is found no need to iterate so use `break` and `match not found` message should not be print inside while loop. please refer below code for understanding.

```
 int flag = 0;
    while((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
    if(strcmp(dirp->dname,filename) == 0)
    {
     print("match found");
     flag = 1;
     break;
    }
    }
    if(flag == 0)
    printf("match not found");
```